# Wil my HTC Desire auto-adjust for daylight savings?

Tags: htc-desire, alarm, date-and-time

Daylight savings is about to end, I was just wondering - will my HTC Desire auto-adjust for this?

Thanks!

(Need to set my alarm tomorrow morning and want that extra hour of sleep!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Date and Time` and ensure your time zone is properly set.  This should be enough, but you can also check `Automatic` or `Use network time` or similar to ensure it picks up the proper time.

Answer (score 4):

If you've got your time zone settings set correctly then yes, it should be fine. If you are in any doubt you can set it to automatically pick up the time from your network.